# Field Values are not accessible in CTX Formula in SAP CPQ

Tags: sap

I am doing a POC for SAP CPQ and my web application and I need to open my web page in SAP CPQ as iFrame. I followed below steps -
1 - Created a Custom Field in Quote.
2 - Created a Custom Quote Tab in Quote.
3 - Using Expression to form URL for iFrame.

Below is Expression format for creating URL -
https://test.com/?p1=v1&id=<*CTX(Quote.CustomField(custom field name) )*>

From above expression, below part is not getting evaluated.
<*CTX(Quote.CustomField(custom field name) )*>

Any help or pointer for this issue?

I connected with various SAP experienced guys, they say it should come. After verifying Custom Fields permissions and all. Then they are not sure where is the issue.